# How can I pass multiple rows to a columns in sql?

Tags: sql, database, view

I have this table

[image]

I need to pass the rows of the column brothers to others columns, like this.
[image]

how can I do it?
I think that I can't use the function PIVOT because I don't know how many rows there will be. and i can't set a limit for the number of rows.

Comment: How can you have same column names in one table?

Comment: First, photographs of data are not helpful. More to the point, why are you trying to construct data in that format?

Comment: sorry I mean something like "brother1, breother2,brother3.......brotherN"

Comment: I only usethis format for the example

Comment: May be something like this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9b44cb87-c0bb-4f84-96f3-30836431dec6/pivot-rows-to-columns-dynamically?forum=transactsql